# Unable to change the value of a variable of my fragment from an external class

Tags: android, variables, fragment

I am working with `fragments` but I am not able to access its variables from an external class.

Currently, I have a fragment `fragmentView` which has a settings `button`. Whenever it is pressed, it shows an UI Element to define different settings.  I copy the code that I have:

**Fragment**

```
 public static Boolean show = false;


 private void initSettingsPanel() {
    m_settingsBtn = (ImageButton) m_activity.findViewById(R.id.settingButton);

    /* click settings panel button to open or close setting panel. */
    m_settingsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            m_settingsLayout = (LinearLayout) m_activity.findViewById(R.id.settingsPanelLayout);
            if (m_settingsLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                m_settingsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (m_settingsPanel == null) {
                    m_settingsPanel = new SettingsPanel(m_activity, show); //HERE I CALL THE EXTERNAL CLASS
                }
            } else {
                m_settingsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

**SettingsPanel**

```
    private Activity m_activity;
    private static Boolean p_show;
    private Switch p_switch;


    public SettingsPanel(Activity activity, Boolean show
) {
      p_show = show;
      m_activity = activity;
      initUIElements(); // Init switch
}

    private void initUIElements() {

      p_switch = (Switch) m_activity.findViewById(R.id.showSwitch);
      setUIListeners();
}

    private void setUIListeners() {

      p_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            p_show = isChecked;
        }
    });
  }
  }
```

What is currently happening is that when I activate the switch I change the value of th evariable of `Pannel` but it does not affect to the fragment. Why? Is there any other way to change the value of its variables not sending to `SettingPanel` each of the variables? Is it at least a correct way to do it?

Comment: I think you need to use interface to send back the value from settingsPanel to your fragment.

Comment: I am currently using this panel for other vars (myVar.method()), and they work. But when I tried to simply change the value of the boolean, it does not. I assume that p_show is a new instance of the variable so even if I change its value the original one will not be affected. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I have created an `abstract class` in order to `get` and `set` the variables:

**ShowVar**

```
public abstract class ShowVar {
  static private Boolean show = false;
  public Boolean getShow() {
    return show;
  } 

  public void setShow(Boolean value) {
    this.show = value;
  } 
}
```

From my `SettingPanel` I have instance `ShowVar` to set the new values of the variable each time and change the `switch`

**SettingsPanel**

```
public class SettingsPanel {
public ShowVar showVar = new ShowVar() {
        @Override
        public void set_Show(Boolean show) {
            super.setShow(show);
        }

    };
}
```

and from my fragment I have access to the values by using my variable `m_settingsPanel`

**Fragment**

```
m_settingsPanel.showVar.getShow()
```

Comment: Hey @Mario, you can register an interface between your activity and fragment. You can pass any data back to your activity. Not sure, why you need an abstract class?

Answer (score 1):

You can register an interface between your activity and your fragment(s) -

```
public interface CallbackInterface {
  //you can also return values from this interface
  void performSomething(); //Add params to this method as per yourneed
}
```

In your activity class -

```
public YourActity extends AppCompactActivity implements CallbackInterface {

//your interface instance
private CallbackInterface mCallbackInterface;

@Override
void performSomething() {
 // Write your code here.
}
}
```

}

In your fragment, you can override the

> onAttach()

to register to the interface --

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
  super.onAttach(context);
  mCallbackInterface = (CallbackInterface) context;
}
```

Voila! Now you can use this interface to send any data back to your activity.

Comment: The reason thst I ended up using an abstract class is because my class is not exactly the one posted, but more complex. Furthermore,  I needed various implementations of the same kind share a common behavior, so an abstract class was needed.